# Discord Webhook Embeds with JavaScript POST Requests

Tags: javascript, json, discord

I tried to create an embed message using a discord webhook and a javascript post method.
Here's the method I use:

```html
function requestWithoutAjax( url, params, method ){
    
    params = params || {};
    method = method || 'post';

    // function to remove the iframe
    var removeIframe = function( iframe ){
        iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
    };
    
    // make a iframe...
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = 'none';
    
    iframe.onload = function(){
        var iframeDoc = this.contentWindow.document;
        
        // Make a invisible form
        var form = iframeDoc.createElement('form');
        form.method = method;
        form.action = url;
        iframeDoc.body.appendChild(form);
        
        // pass the parameters
        for( var name in params ){
            var input = iframeDoc.createElement('input');
            input.type = 'hidden';
            input.name = name;
            input.value = params[name];
            form.appendChild(input);
        }
        
        form.submit();
        // remove the iframe
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            removeIframe(iframe);
        }, 500);
    };
    
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

When I try to call this method with this JSON: `{"content":"Some message"}` the webhook sends "Some message" into my discord chat.
But when I try to use an embed (https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook & https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object), with this JSON: `{"embeds":[{"title":"A title","description":"A description","color":3447003}]}` it just doesn't send the embed message.
Am I formatting the JSON wrong, or is it something other?
Maybe someone of you can solve my problem.

Comment: What response are you getting? 400 Bad request?

Comment: @LW001 Yes, exactly